# Custom Flex TextArea with html code completion

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex-spark

I made a text/html editor app but I want to add code hinting. Right now I'm using a basic Spark textures. What steps are involved in implementing code hinting/completion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this project help you.

[Moonshine 0.8 Beta 2](http://code.google.com/p/moonshineproject/) just out now with basic auto-completion. Parses SWCs and source files.